# File size in python3 for mac os x not matching command line result

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to get the size of a file just downloaded by using urllib in python3. I tried to get the filesize with len(response.read()) and the value got was 653856. However when this done I found after checking that the size of the file saved was 0 (did the response.read() consume the data maybe?) so I discarded this option and switched to ckeck the size with os:

```
if strFecha in dicc or fecha.year < 2010:
    # Download the file from `url` and save it locally under `nomFichero`:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(nomFichero, 'wb') as outFile:
        # Following one returns 653856
        size1 = len(response.read())
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, outFile)  
        # Following two lines return 524288
        size2 = os.path.getsize(nomFichero)
        size2 = os.stat(nomFichero).st_size
```

I got the same result for both of them (524288), but after doing an 'ls -l' on the command line I got 653856, and I don't know why this value did not match the one got from python.

Can anyone tell me which value is the good one and how to get it with python3?

Comment: what is 'll'? do an ls -l

Comment: With 'll' I meant 'ls -l', I edited the question for clearing it up

Comment: Can you post an [mcve] of this? Is the file flushed and closed when you're checking the size from python?

Comment: What OS X version are you on?

Comment: Using OS X El Capitan. 10.11.6

Comment: Move these checks outside the `with` and see what numbers you get. This just seems like buffering.

Comment: @pvg: Thanks for your comment, it worked great. Thanks for your suggestion!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect this has to do with block sizing & empty blocks.

If you have say a **2,324,020** **byte** file there will be two values, *size on disk* (how much room is being used to store it because of the file system's minimum allowed space usage)

and *actual file size* OR *Logical File Size* (2,324,020  byte). for instance on Windows 7, I have a 2,324,020 byte file; it's size on disk is 2,326,528 bytes.

Python's OS commands

```
os.path.getsize #Returns real size of file in bytes
```

and

```
os.stat #Returns real size of file in bytes
```

Will return the exact size of the file in bytes.

Something like this:

```
lSize=os.stat(filename).st_size
bSize=os.statvfs(filename).f_bsize
sizeOnDisk=(lSize/bSize+1)*bSize
```

will return the size on disk but is not supported on Windows at this time.

### EDIT

[This post](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1368017/html/GUID-FCEE7434-7D7C-4EF2-9081-C58184044A94.html) says LS does NOT show disk usage size, rather logical size, however notes that  "empty blocks" may alter the file size.

> The output of the ls command displays only the size of a file and does
> not include indirect blocks used by the file. Any empty blocks of the
> file also get included in the output of the command.

It is worth noting if you are looking for Logical File Size, Python stat would be ideal.

Comment: Please explain the down vote so I can append the answer. Thank you!

Comment: OS X `ls -l` returns file size in bytes, file sizes are never measured in bits so this answer is almost but not entirely unrelated to the question.

Comment: The example applies to all files. For instance a I have a file 2.21mb (2,324,020 bytes) that takes up (2,326,528 bytes). More size on disk than the "real" file size/byte count.

Comment: Will update to reflect bytes as example instead of bits.

Comment: It does not apply to all files. It applies to programs that show files size in blocks. `ls -`l does not, neither does stat.

Comment: Unless I am missing something this link: http://the-hydra.blogspot.com/2011/07/stat-or-ls-which-one-showing-correct.html show LS -l uses a more general relation to block sizing and is not a accurate as stat; thus ls -l can yield a different answer and stat will yield the proper answer.

Comment: You are missing something, that blog post is about the number of *blocks* reported by each command. They both report the same number of *bytes* which is what the question is about. Of course, the user is also running OS X, not linux.

Comment: OS X ls -l seems to use space on disk according to this answer (read first comment on question too) https://superuser.com/questions/68559/file-size-returned-from-ls-linux-vs-os-x

Comment: No it doesn't. There is nothing in the question that directly suggests that and the comment specifically says the individual file size is in bytes. Why don't you try it yourself or at least, consider that you might be wrong instead of running around the internet looking at straws to grab on to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158888/discussion-between-steven-byrne-and-pvg).